# How to add spatial reference information in distance calculation?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, coordinates

Software: ArcGIS Pro

I have a long polyline with multiple vertices. I want shape length of only a portion of this polyline.
For that I have extracted the coordinates of all vertices of this long polyline and created a list. I have removed the coordinates from this list which are not required, so that I have a list of coordinates only of the portion whose shape length is required.

Now i need to calculate the shape length using this coordinates list. For that i have used the following code:

```
import numpy as np
def dist_from_point_list(point_list):
    line = np.array(point_list, float)
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((line[1:] - line[:-1])**2, -1)).sum()
print(dist_from_point_list(point_list))
```

When I measure the distance in ArcGIS Pro, the shape length is different from what I get using this function in my code. I have to somehow use the spatial reference information in my code to get the correct spatial length.

I tried as follows:

```
feature_info = [[(469741.90079999994, 233745.38800000027), (469741.4121000003, 233745.19480000064), (469741.1469999999, 233745.08999999985), (469742.0535000004, 233743.93400000036), (469742.95999999996, 233742.77800000086), (469743.1457000002, 233741.93960000016), (469744.3021, 233736.71729999967), (469744.6370000001, 233735.20500000007), (469744.9084000001, 233734.10789999925), (469744.95710000023, 233733.9110000003), (469745.82519999985, 233730.40210000053), (469745.9199999999, 233730.0189999994), (469747.1799999997, 233724.37299999967), (469746.95799999963, 233723.80000000075), (469747.4139999999, 233722.3440000005), (469747.56900000013, 233721.86690000072), (469747.6469999999, 233721.73399999924), (469750.0284000002, 233713.38040000014), (469750.4979999997, 233711.73299999908), (469751.28199999966, 233710.97399999946), (469751.4919999996, 233710.39699999988), (469825.6730000004, 233504.0979999993), (469825.26400000043, 233504.92899999954), (469813.48900000006, 233531.3560000006), (469813.3729999997, 233531.6129999999), (469801.8559999997, 233561.35799999908), (469800.2570000002, 233563.26400000043), (469797.0800000001, 233570.77600000054), (469793.90299999993, 233578.28800000064), (469792.6009999998, 233580.41200000048), (469797.7457999997, 233582.2851999998), (469799.33100000024, 233582.86240000091), (469801.6150000002, 233583.69400000013), (469794.9391999999, 233599.6598000005), (469792.40390000027, 233605.72309999913), (469789.87600000016, 233611.7689999994), (469789.3559999997, 233613.37900000066), (469786.5020000003, 233620.32799999975), (469783.6370000001, 233627.3230000008), (469780.784, 233634.3440000005), (469777.8969999999, 233641.32200000063), (469775.2419999996, 233648.27800000086), (469772.51400000043, 233655.12189999968), (469769.9369999999, 233661.77999999933), (469765.5580000002, 233672.3900000006), (469764.8053000001, 233674.33830000088), (469761.61199999973, 233682.60400000028), (469757.9497999996, 233691.7310000006), (469757.62590000033, 233692.5382000003), (469756.5080000004, 233695.3239999991), (469754.17619999964, 233702.33110000007), (469753.43620000035, 233704.55440000072), (469752.5036000004, 233707.35669999942), (469751.57100000046, 233710.15909999982), (469751.4919999996, 233710.39699999988), (469750.87399999984, 233710.21829999983), (469914.5789999999, 233428.50999999978), (469914.88609999977, 233428.49760000035), (469916.05510000046, 233428.45069999993), (469918.4615000002, 233426.21199999936), (469921.8501000004, 233423.05959999934), (469930.1710000001, 233473.81299999915), (469929.324, 233474.09200000018), (469928.5959999999, 233470.64100000076), (469927.5410000002, 233466.39790000021), (469923.9411000004, 233456.26070000045), (469922.7379999999, 233452.87299999967), (469920.59530000016, 233446.5427000001), (469920.07799999975, 233445.01449999958), (469918.75739999954, 233441.11319999956), (469918.43099999987, 233440.1490000002), (469916.59669999965, 233433.80859999917), (469916.2450000001, 233432.59300000034), (469914.65809999965, 233428.70390000008), (469914.5789999999, 233428.50999999978), (469914.44600000046, 233428.54900000058), (469914.0614, 233428.11099999957), (469908.3674999997, 233421.62629999965), (469905.82799999975, 233418.73399999924), (469906.2189999996, 233418.75), (469906.31900000013, 233418.66200000048), (469912.2860000003, 233413.43989999965), (469912.1730000004, 233413.30599999987), (469911.7759999996, 233413.22199999914), (469904.25320000015, 233419.67679999955), (469901.9397, 233421.66169999912), (469899.4305999996, 233423.81460000016), (469889.17399999965, 233432.61500000022), (469880.9966000002, 233439.99540000036), (469875.89800000004, 233444.59699999914), (469861.96800000034, 233458.4539999999), (469852.60720000044, 233468.59249999933), (469845.44099999964, 233476.35400000028), (469838.574, 233483.48179999925), (469835.5120000001, 233486.66000000015), (469834.8194000004, 233488.11759999953), (469832.3590000002, 233493.29499999993), (469830.5712000001, 233496.18359999917), (469825.6730000004, 233504.0979999993), (469824.4938000003, 233500.06020000018)]]
features = []

for feature in feature_info:
    # Create a Polyline object based on the array of points
    # Append to the list of Polyline objects
    features.append(arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*coords) for coords in feature])))

# Persist a copy of the Polyline objects using CopyFeatures
tmp = arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(features, "memory/lineSegment")
length = [f[0] for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tmp, 'SHAPE@LENGTH', spatial_reference=arcpy.SpatialReference(27700))][0]

print(length)
```

The length found is : 1074.598630135699

whereas the shape length from arcgis pro is : 471.116806

I don't see an option to upload the shape file used in my test :(

Why is this difference in length??

Comment: There's a couple of issues here. First off, you don't specify the coordinate system. Second, you don't provide coordinate values for others to check your work. Third, you don't seem to understand the code you're using to compute Cartesian distance between first and last points (and how that might differ from path length). Finally, the title, instead of describing the problem, describes what you think the solution might be (and given the code provided, seems unlikely). Please [Edit] the Question to provide coordinate reference, sample coordinates, the value you computed, and what Pro measured.

Answer (score 1):

Using arcpy, you should probably create a [Polyline](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/polyline.htm) object from the coordinates you have extracted, set the correct spatial reference, and then use its `length` property (cartesian length) or `getLength()`.